# Laravel ajax 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to do an ajax call in laravel. The ajax call logs my data how I want it, but keeps giving me the 500 error. I've read that you need to set the _token in the data field. But that doesn't work for me. So, I can log all the data, but ones I want to push it to the DB I keep getting this error.

Here's my code.

Script.js

```
$('.likeBtn').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var userid=$(this).siblings('input[name=userID]');
console.log(userid[0].value);
var useridarticle=$(this).siblings('input[name=userIdFk]');
console.log(useridarticle[0].value);
var articleid=$(this).siblings('input[name=articleId]');
console.log(articleid[0].value);
var token=$(this).siblings('input[name=_token]');
console.log(token[0].value);

$.ajax({
    url:"articles" ,
    type: "post",
    data: {'user_id':userid[0].value,
        'article_id':articleid[0].value,
        'user_id_fk':useridarticle[0].value,
        '_token': token[0].value},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
});
```

Controller.

```
if(Request::ajax()) {
        $data = Input::all();
        print_r($data);
}
```

My tokens are set in the header of my master.blade

```
  <meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/>
```

And at the end of my master.blade

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
    });
```

What am I not seeing? FYI, You might ask why I need does variables. I need them because I generate the same form in  a foreach. This works fine for me, i get the data that I want so.

Comment: 500 error doesn't necessarily mean CSRF token errors. Have you checked the error log?

Comment: If you're using chrome you can view the AJAX request in the *Network* tab in the development console. What error is it throwing? 500 is a *generic* error. Or you could look, as @Mysteryos said, in /storage/logs

Comment: When I click on the error that I logged, it says anonymous function about this `$.ajax({` When I look at the Network tab there is the name articles(name of my page) in red, with type `xhr` and `jquery.min.js:4`

Comment: Actually the _network tab_ helped me quite well, there was a big error on the Controller side. Thankyou!